How do I get custom colors using color chooser from tkinter
In the askcolor function of class Chooser in the pop up you can add color to a custom colors list. I was wondering if I can somehow get the values of those colors, but I could not find a way how to do it.
Code for the pop up:
from tkinter import colorchooser
color_code = colorchooser.askcolor()

Pop up screen shot:


As far as I know the custom colors can't be queried set ahead of time

The function tkinter.colorchooser.askcolor() doesn't directly provide access to the custom colors list in its popup. The function's main role is to return the selected color.
The closest you can get is keeping track of the colors by creating a list (custom_colors = []) and then every time color_code = colorchooser.askcolor() is called, .append to the list. E.g.:
from tkinter import colorchooser, Tk, Button
root = Tk()
custom_colors = []

def choose_color():
    color_code = colorchooser.askcolor()
    if color_code[1]:
        if color_code[1] not in custom_colors:
            custom_colors.append(color_code[1])

    print(custom_colors)


choose_button = Button(root, text="Choose Color", command=choose_color)
choose_button.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()


Do you think that its worth trying to make another function to the class chooser that would give me those values?

@Unix You would have to modify the tkinter.colorchooser module. I'm not sure how simple/possible this would be to get/set the values of all of the custom color values.
It will probably be a lot of work and you might have to replace the askcolor() function.
It might be simpler to create your own custom color picker window in Tkinter.

yeah it probably will be I was looking through the module found there, command = "tk_chooseColor" refers to somewhere in tcltk module and there I founds https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/main/doc/chooseColor.n this which doesnt really help because I dont even know what language this is in  welp I guess i will give up

@Unix: the format of that file is the troff typesetting language, using the 'man' (manual page) module. It's the raw version of the man pages rather than the code for the color chooser.
